# Android - event queue - execute after preference set

Tags: java, android, event-handling, android-preferences

I'm rescheduling alerts after property change. I need to read various variables. The problem is, when I run the function from `OnPreferenceChangeListener`, this function sees old value of preference.

I've wanted to do something I know from AWT/Swing development: add command to event queue, so that it will be executed after processed UI events, it means also after finishing preference change operation. The problem is... I've found nothing similar to `EventQueue` in Android. I've found only `runOnUiThread` operation, which is not what I need, because according to specification the command will be immediately executed, if we already are in UI thread.

So, could you please help me, what I need to use? Maybe I've searched for wrong keyword....

Comment: "The problem is, when I run the function from OnPreferenceChangeListener, this function sees old value of preference." -- that should not happen.

Comment: It is so, because this listener can cancel the change, so it is commited after this method finishes

Comment: `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` cannot "cancel the change".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I was using wrong the `OnPreferenceChangeListener` is used during preference change phase, is registered on single preference and should be used for preference value validation.

This what I needed was to register the listener that will be called after the preference is already changed. This task is done with `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`, that will be called after any preference is changed and the change is already visible to the app:

```
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
            new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            if (MYKEY1.equals(key) 
                    || MYKEY2.equals(key)) {
                 doSomething();
            }
        }
    });
```